# How to rearrange terms in an expression to a particular form (e.g. A/w-> A*(1/w)

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement, pattern-matching, expression-manipulation, algebraic-manipulation

I have a huge expression for which the numerators are a big mess, involving numbers, variables, formal sums and unevaluted function, let's call the numerators Ai, with i=1,2,...n

This "beast" is divided by some power of w for each term, so for example A1/w^2+A2/w^4 etc.

It is vital that I change the form of this expression *without deleting and reinserting the powers of w through term by term by hand*.

How can I do this? I tried /. x_/w^2 -> x*(1/w^2) but this does nothing.
***Edit: upon trying to copy and paste here the form mathematica gives and the form I want, I realised the problem. Mathematica doesn't distinguise the two outputs: A/w^2 and (1/w^2)*A. So, I've used below a screenshot of what I want to obtain.

Here's an example term of what I'm talking about, Mathematica gives me this,

$
\frac{8 A^3 \sigma  \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \left(\frac{2 A (n+1)^4 e^{-\frac{A (n+1)}{w^2}} \left(\sum _{m=0}^{\infty } w^m \sigma ^n a(n+1,m)\right)}{w^3}+(n+1)^3 e^{-\frac{A (n+1)}{w^2}} \left(\sum _{m=0}^{\infty } m w^{m-1} \sigma ^n a(n+1,m)\right)\right)}{w^9}$,

for which the code is,

```
(8*A^3*\[Sigma]*
   Sum[((1 + n)^3*
        Sum[m*w^(-1 + m)*\[Sigma]^n*a[1 + n, m], {m, 0, Infinity}])/
      E^((A*(1 + n))/w^2) + 
          (2*A*(1 + n)^4*
        Sum[w^m*\[Sigma]^n*a[1 + n, m], {m, 0, 
          Infinity}])/(E^((A*(1 + n))/w^2)*w^3), {n, 0, Infinity}])/
 w^9
```

whereas I want this:

[image: what I want to obtain]

Comment: Try [`Collect`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Collect.html)?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Please show at least a portion  of the expression you are trying to modify and how you would like it to look afterward.

Comment: Collect leaves it in the same form I'm afraid..

Comment: @NoamTamarin Then we definitely need to have an example of your expression: `Collect[x/w + y/w^2 + (3 + a)^5/w + r/w^2 - 56 - 4/w^3, w]` works as expected for example (unless I am misunderstanding what you want?)

Comment: I've edited the question to include an example of what I meant

Comment: When posting questions please include Mathematica code in InputForm so that people can copy and paste the expressions into a notebook.

Comment: `A*(1/w)` is typeset as `A/w` in `Standard` form -- There's no choice. The expression is `Times[A, Power[w, -1]]`. I assume this is really a question about [tag:output-formatting] rather about simplifying or manipulating expressions.

Comment: Close?: `expr /. {e : Power[E, _] :> e, p : Power[w, _] :> HoldForm[p]}`

Comment: Try: `expr  /.  x_/w^9 -> HoldForm[HoldForm[1/w^9] x]`